# Within abstract class def of Mumble<T> I want to create an object of class Mumble<Integer>. How?

Tags: java, generics, instance

I'm creating an abstract generic class; let's call it `Mumble<T>`.  Within it is a method I'm going to use to have it test itself (`selfTest()`); to do so I need an object of class `Mumble<Integer>`, in whatever subclass I'm testing.  For instance, if `Bumble<T>` extends `Mumble<T>`, then I'll invoke `selfTest()` on an object of class `Bumble<Whatever>`, or just plain `Bumble`, whereupon `Mumble` should create an object of class `Bumble<Integer>` for testing purposes.

How can I do this?

Comment: You'll have to give us a code example.

Comment: Why isn't the instance itself (i.e. this) enough for the self test? Do you need to create an additional instance of the same subclass type? (why?)

Comment: The issue as I see it is that from the compiler's point of view 'this' is of class Mumble<T>, but I need to treat it as a Mumble<Integer>.  Due to erasure, they're the same once we get past the compiler; the problem may be mostly in my head.

Answer (score 3):

If your method is called with an instance of the subclass, you can find the class of the instance and do `newInstance()`.  However, this means that your class must have a parameterless constructor, and that must suit your needs.

A little fancier is to call `getConstructors()` and find the specific parameterized constructor you want, then invoke `newInstance(parms)` on that.

But if you don't have an instance of the subclass to test (and you're not, eg, told the name of the subclass) then you're SOL.  (But, of course, in the scenario you describe `this` is the needed instance.)

Comment: Hey Hot Licks, sorry, I was editing my answer and haven't read yours before posting the update. You have proposed the reflection approach before I did. Anyway, I will keep my update because of the concrete example, but credit for the reflection part is yours (+1).

Comment: @AnthonyAccioly - No sweat!  And you point out a detail I failed to mention which is that the generic parameter is both unavailable and irrelevant at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

The main trick is that `this` will always point to the actual instance. Also keep in mind that at runtime, `Bumble<Integer>` is just `Bumble`:

So:

```
abstract class Mumble<T> {
    public void selfTest() {
         Mumble obj = this;
    }
} 
class Bumble<T> extends Mumble<T> {
}
```

If you do:

```
Mumble<Integer> m = new Bumble<Integer>();
m.selfTest();
```

The actual type of `obj` will be `Bumble`.

---

But if you really want to create a `new` independent instance, just keep an abstract method around and implement it inside every sub-class:

```
abstract class Mumble<T> {
    public abstract Mumble<Integer> getInstance();
    public void selfTest() {
         Mumble<Integer> obj = getInstance();
    }
} 

class Bumble<T> extends Mumble<T> {
    @Override
    public Mumble<Integer> getInstance() {
       return new Bumble<Integer>();
    }
}
```

If you call `new Bumble<String>().selfTest();`, `obj` will be an independent instance of `Bumble` and you don't have to worry about anything actually returning a String.

---

Finally `Mumble<Integer>` is just `Mumble` at runtime (because of type erasure). So, if you can adhere to some kind of standard (like making sure that every subclass of Mumble have an empty constructor, or a standard constructor of some kind) nothing stops you from using some dirty reflection trick to make it work (as @Hot Licks originally proposed):

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Mumble<Integer> reflectInstance() throws Exception {
   Class<? extends Mumble> clazz = getClass();
   // Dirty implicit unchecked cast
   Mumble<Integer> obj = clazz.newInstance();
   return obj;
}
```

The entire thing can be reduced to `return getClass().newInstance();` I expanded it to explain what is going on (also in real world code please do something about exceptions).

---

Check out my [Working Example](http://ideone.com/ApXjds) that demonstrates all of the above techniques.